# Is the regular representation of a given finite group unique?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory

I'm currently studying group theory for the first time and I can't find the answer to a question. I know that the regular representation of a finite group is always completely reducible and that it contains all the irreducible representations.

But is it unique?

If I took the most simplified form of this representation in a given basis and then changed the basis while maintaining the fact that the representation is completely reduced, will I find the same matrix/operator?

Thanks in advance for your answer.

Comment: The regular representation is unique up to equivalence. What definition of "regular representation" are you using where this could be in question?

Comment: The course syllabus defined it as a representation that contains all irreducible representations of a group. There was another topological definition directly linked but we don't use it.

Comment: That "definition" is vague. There are plenty of reps which contain every irrep but which are not the regular rep.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The course syllabus defined it as a representation that contains all irreducible representations of a group.

This is the wrong definition. The regular representation of a (finite, for simplicity) group $G$ over a field $K$ is the action of $G$ on the group algebra $K[G]$ by left multiplication. It is a *specific* representation and so is unique by definition. If $K$ is algebraically closed and has characteristic not dividing $|G|$ it can also be characterized up to isomorphism as containing every irreducible representation $V$ with multiplicity $\dim V$.